# Multiple each cell within range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying (and failing) to use Google Apps Script (JavaScript) to do the following:

1. Copy Values from one sheet to another **(working)**
2. If cell 'G3' on 'Cal' sheet displays "Dollars" then I want to multiply all the cells within the range from 'Buy' (that get pasted on line 11) by Convertnum (which has a value of 10).
   e.g. If "dollars" is in G3 and "1000" has been pasted in every cell from C2 down, I then want multiple all these cells (from C2 down) by the value in H3 (sheet 'Cal') which is 10. ** (Not working)**

Sorry if this is not explained that well. I have been trying for 24 hours and this is the best I have come up with. Can anyone suggest how I can overcome this?

p.s I'm very new to JavaScript.

```
function PasteValues() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var SKU = ss.getRange('lanparte!A8:A160');
  var Buy = ss.getRange('lanparte!I8:I160');
  var Convert = ss.getRange('Cal!G3');
  var Convertnum = ss.getRange('Cal!H3');
  var Sell = ss.getRange('Output!C2:C160');

  SKU.copyTo(ss.getRange('Output!A2'), {contentsOnly: true});
  Buy.copyTo(ss.getRange('Output!B2'), {contentsOnly: true});
  Buy.copyTo(ss.getRange('Output!C2'), {contentsOnly: true});

  if (Convert == "Dollars") {
    for each (var cell as Sell) {
      var timescell = Number(cell)*Number(Convertnum);
      Sell.setValue(timescell);
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes it's more convenient to convert `range` into `array` in Google Apps Script.

I suggest change lines with Convert, Convertum:

```
  // add .getValue() to range object
  var Convert = ss.getRange('Cal!G3').getValue();
  var Convertnum = ss.getRange('Cal!H3').getValue();
```

Second proplem is your `for each` loop: as far as I know, this construction is invalid. You may use this piece of code:

```
  if (Convert == "Dollars") {
    // convert range into array
    var NewVals = Sell.getValues();

    // multiply
    for (var i = 0; i < NewVals.length; i++) {
      NewVals[i][0] *= Convertnum;
    }

    // set new values
    Sell.setValues(NewVals);
  }
```

Comment: You are my hero! Thanks so much!!

Comment: `for each` is not a thing, but [`forEach()` is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).